# Should have been used 'preposition' in following sentence

Tags: prepositions, participles

"Any citizen of India of full age and capacity can make a declaration renouncing his citizenship."

This is a sentence from my polity book.

In the above sentence, should we use "of" between the declaration and renouncing?

Like, ....can we make a declaration of renouncing his citizenship.

Or, was 'denouncing' used as a participle?

Has 'denouncing' been used as participle the which one it is modifying — 'Any citizen' or 'declaration'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Renouncing his citizenship" is indeed a participial phrase, modifying "a statement".

"A statement of renouncing" would be fine (with "renouncing" as a verbal noun - though "renunciation" would be more common in British English - I don't know about Indian English).

But for that to take a complement you would need to make it into an *-ing* clause, "renouncing/renunciation **of** his citizenship": but this would be much clumsier than the original.